# App crash when using QPainter on QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qpixmap

I am trying to make a class that will make a dot graphic. The class inherits from QWidget. I want it to draw lines and dots on a QPixmap that will be displayed in a QLabel.

The constructor of the class looks like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    calcul_proprietes(); // Function that makes calculation of what to draw.
    pix = new QPixmap(760,350);

    dessiner_graphique(); // Function that does the drawing.

    //Displaying the qpixmap
    layout_principal = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    label_pix = new QLabel(this);
    label_pix->setPixmap(*pix);
    layout_principal->addWidget(label_pix);
    this->setLayout(layout_principal);
}
```

And a short part of the function that does the drawing

```
void MyClass::dessiner_graphique()
{
    // ...
    QPainter painter(pix);
    QRect contour(x_depart,y_depart,largeur_grille,hauteur_grille);
    painter.drawRect(contour);
    // ...
}
```

I don't want to use the paintEvent function because it gets called all the time and i only need my graphic to be painted once. What do i do wrong?

Comment: We'd need to see more of your code to tell what exactly you're doing wrong.

Comment: Actually it works for me (Windows 8.1, Qt 5.4.1, VS 2013). So please describe the problem. By the way I think you don't need to store the `layout` and the `pixmap` as a member variable, or do you use it later as well ?

Comment: @Venemo: All my drawing code works if i put it in paintEvent but it crashes when i try doing it with the pixmap. So the rest of the drawing code is not really relevant.

Comment: @vizhanyolajos With this code, the app will crash without compiler error message.

Comment: @vizhanyolajos And since the pixmap is used in a function and not directly in the constructor I figured it would be easier to make it a member variable rather than passing an argument to the function.

Comment: The posted code looks okay to me (although the call to this->setLayout() is unnecessary; it's enough to have specified (this) as an argument to the QVBoxLayout constructor).  The next thing you should do is determine which exact line the program crashes while executing.  You can do that with a debugger, or by sprinkling printf() or qDebug() statements around and seeing which ones print last before the crash.

Comment: @Antoine LeBrun: What I could tested was worked fine. But you didn't post your full code, so of course there can be bugs, but we won't be able to help you until you don't show us the buggy part of your code. As said, debug it where the problem is, or at least tell us the error message.

Comment: No crash info? Apart from that it could be that the paint device is not initialized correctly. Maybe need to call begin()?